# C++: Swapping pointed-to variables

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverseString(char* first, char* last)
{
    while(first < last)
    {
        cout << *first << " " << *last << endl; //for debugging; prints 'H' and 'o' then crashes
        char temp = *last;
        *last = *first; //this line crashes the program
        *first = temp;
        first++;
        last--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* s = "Hello";
    reverseString(s, s + strlen(s) - 1);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

However, I'm having trouble swapping the values to which the pointers point.  I thought *p = *p1 should just set the pointed-to value of p to the pointed-to value of p1, but something seems bugged up.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you don't need to implement this yourself, prefer `std::reverse`.

Comment: I know, but I would really like to know why it isn't working the way I have it set up.  Thanks for the tip, by the way.

Comment: You're modifying a string literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code looks fine to me.  The most likely problem is that the compiler is allowed to assume that string literals are not modified, so it can put them in read-only memory.  Try

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

in `main()` instead, which creates a *writable copy* of the string literal.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I never knew about read-only memory.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to @j_random_hacker:

```
char* buffer = new char[32];
strcpy(buffer, "Hello");
reverseString(buffer, buffer + strlen(buffer) - 1);

... rest of your program ...

delete[] buffer;
```

This properly allocates memory for a C-style string which can then be modified by any function. Of course, you need to include `<string.h>` header to access `strcpy` and `strlen`.

Comment: I would +1, but the fact that you say "properly allocates" suggests that using a local array on the stack (as I proposed) is somehow "improper" :-P

Comment: It's not. I just feel all warm and fuzzy knowing I decide when my arrays get de-allocated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Header file for strlen() is missing.

Second, it throws a warning - Deprecated conversion from string constant to char*, @j_random_hacker's solution seems to take care of this issue.